# Scala `view`: `force` is not a member of `Seq`

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

It appears that applying `map` and `filter` somehow converts a `view` into a `Seq`. The [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) contains this example:

```
> (v.view map (_ + 1) map (_ * 2)).force
res12: Seq[Int] = Vector(4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22)
```

But if I do something similar, I get an error:

```
> val a = Array(1,2,3)
> s.view.map(_ + 1).map(_ + 1).force
<console>:67: error: value force is not a member of Seq[Int]
```

It seems that if I `map` over an `Array` `view` more than once the `SeqView` becomes a `Seq`.

```
> a.view.map(_+1)
res212: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Array[Int]] = SeqViewM(...)
> a.view.map(_+1).map(_+1)
res211: Seq[Int] = SeqViewMM(...)
```

I suspect this behavior may have something to do with `Array` being a mutable collection, as I cannot replicate this behavior with `List` or `Vector`. I can however `filter` the `Array` `view` as many times as I like.

Comment: Weird, looks like a bug in the REPL, because my IDE types this correctly. If you can get more feedback on this, maybe you should file a bug.

Comment: Using scala's IDE I get the same error when attempting to do `a.view.map(_ + 1).map(_ + 1).force`

Comment: Though, it will let me do `.asInstanceOf[SeqView[Int, Array[Int]]].force` on it without complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro tip: when debugging implicits in the REPL, `reify` from `reflect` is your friend.

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe.reify
scala> import collection.mutable._ // To clean up reified exprs
scala> reify(a.view.map(_ + 1).map(_ * 2))
Expr[Seq[Int]](Predef.intArrayOps($read.a).view.map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))(IndexedSeqView.arrCanBuildFrom).map(((x$2) => x$2.$times(2)))(Seq.canBuildFrom))
```

By design, `IndexedSeqView.arrCanBuildFrom` produces not another `IndexedSeqView`, but a plain old `SeqView`. However, from then on you'd expect `SeqView`s to remain so. In order for that to happen, the `CBF` passed to the second `map` should be `SeqView.canBuildFrom`, but for some reason we are getting the one from `Seq`. Now that we know the issue, let's pass `SeqView.canBuildFrom` manually and dissect the error.

```
scala> a.view.map(_ + 1).map(_ * 2)(collection.SeqView.canBuildFrom)
<console>:??: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [A]scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[collection.SeqView.Coll,A,scala.collection.SeqView[A,Seq[_]]]
    (which expands to)  [A]scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.TraversableView[_, _ <: Traversable[_]],A,scala.collection.SeqView[A,Seq[_]]]
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Array[Int]],Int,?]
       a.view.map(_ + 1).map(_ * 2)(collection.SeqView.canBuildFrom)
                                                       ^
```

Ok, so this is not a bug in implicit resolution or the compiler or anything; it is the library at fault, as the compiler is able to give us a good reason for failing here.

`scalac` requires the second type param to `CBF` be `Int` or a supertype of it here, and since the one we give it takes any `A`, we're good. The third one is unknown, so it can also be anything, also good. Therefore, the problem is in the first.

```
scala> implicitly[collection.SeqView[Int, _] <:< collection.TraversableView[_, _]]
<function1>
```

This narrows the issue down to `Array[Int] <: Traversable[_]`. And there it is. `Array`s are not `Traversable`, so they fail here and are forced to become `Seq`s by the `CBF` in `Seq`.

To fix this, `SeqView` would need to have a `arrCanBuildFrom` like `IndexedSeqView` does. This is a bug in the library. This doesn't relate to `Array` being mutable; it's really because `Array` is not really a collection (it doesn't implement `Traversable`) and has to be shoehorned in.